# Как задать ширину 100% блоку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать fullscreen слайдер, на данный момент задача состоит в том, чтобы блок `.slide` растянуть на всю ширину экрана, допустим я буду это отслеживать с помощью JS при изменении экрана и менять размер блоков `.slide` под размер, но я пробовал задать жестко размер этому классу и ничего не вышло, ширина какой была, такой и осталась, я предполагаю, что это из-за флексов, но не знаю как решить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 border: 4px solid green;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider-track {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 width: 1920px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105950_3727792_a1c6051cd0.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105948_2453824_bf1da0390e.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_7272342_d86ca2e9a3.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_9445757_ead4249574.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: max-width: 100%;

Comment: Я пробовал, это не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно вопрос то не сложный ...

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.items{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.items,.item,.item img{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201548/4facf580dd914ca.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/4/9/512274817997285/devushka-v-belom-na-krovati.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.flywall.ru/image/girls/nozhki-devushki.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.1366x768.net/large/201111/447.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://trenyng.ru/images/kak%20nayti-devushku.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

пример с маленьким слайдером на css3 :

```css
:root {
  --gw: 100vw;
  --gh: 100vh;
  --gww: 400vw;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: var(--gw);
  height: var(--gh);
}

.slider {
  width: var(--gw);
  height: var(--gh);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  width: var(--gww);
  height: var(--gh);
}

.item {
  width: var(--gw);
  height: var(--gh);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.item {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: movi 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes movi {
  0%,
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://ftopx.com/images/201101/ftop.ru_15462.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://imagebank.biz/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/109239.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://wallpaperscave.ru/images/original/18/01-18/women-bikini-11533.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://ero.motaen.com/upload/wallpapers/source/2009/07/16/09/03/10350/celebrities_1525.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы вопрос вообще не поняли, мне надо не слайдер готовый, а мне нужно блоки .slide растянуть на ширину окна браузера.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  исправил ответ

Comment: Нужно что бы они шли в ряд, потому что слайдер будет основан на том, что блок с картинками будет перемещаться относительно экрана с помощью translate, + нужно сделать что бы картинка искажалась под высоту

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ты где такие классные ножки нашел?)))

Comment: @Air в yandex, всё беру в yndex :))

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi я не понимаю тебя ! если вы не можете самое простое то как вы собираетесь писать вообще ui ?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi для items поставь display:flex и всё

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  вот кстати типа слайдера :https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YaRYQr?editors=1100 20 минут у меня ушло на это

Answer (score 1):

`.slide { flex: 0 0 calc(100vw - 8px); }` для того чтобы слайд был на всю ширину вьюпорта.
Минус 8 пикселей - это из-за вашего зеленого бордера шириной в 4.

И `.slide img { width: 100%; }` для заполнения изображением.

Какие-то доп.стили этим классам не требуются. Разве что будет необходимо изображение центровать по высоте (или обрезать), ибо соотношение сторон может не совпадать... но это Вы сообразите.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 border: 4px solid green;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider-track {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 flex: 0 0 calc(100vw - 8px);
}

.slide img {
 width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105950_3727792_a1c6051cd0.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105948_2453824_bf1da0390e.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_7272342_d86ca2e9a3.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_9445757_ead4249574.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю такое решение вам подойдёт.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var slides = $('.slide');
  $('.slider-track').css('width', slides.length * $('.slider').innerWidth() + 'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc( 100vw - 20px);
}

.slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105950_3727792_a1c6051cd0.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105948_2453824_bf1da0390e.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_7272342_d86ca2e9a3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0407/h_1523105947_9445757_ead4249574.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```